# Problems placing columns of text in the centre

Tags: html, css

I would like to place two columns of text next to each other and centre it without having to code in a table like so
[image: click here]

I have been working on the code but for some reason it doesn't centre properly, I was wondering if you could help me with that. I used the columns property, but that did not work either.

Thanks again!

```css
.table.addtop.narrow{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  column-count: 2;
}

.td.english{
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 26px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  radius: 4px;
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table addtop narrow">
        <div class="td english">where?</div>
            <div class="td chokwe">
            <div class="ex">Curi?</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="table addbottom narrow">
        <div class="td english"><span class="u">Where</span> is Antonio's house?</div>
            <div class="td chokwe">
            <div class="ex"><span class="u">xx</span> xxx?</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This clearly IS a `table` so you should use one.

Comment: @Paulie_D `<table>`s are terrible when you try to deliver the best RWD experience. I think that semantically `<dl>` `<dt>` and `<dd>` would be great here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`column-count: 2;` is designed for text, it divides text into X columns:

```css
.column-count-2 {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-count-2">
<h2>Column count example</h2>
<p>Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, as lick i the shoes need to chase tail. Climb a tree, wait for a fireman jump to fireman then scratch his face hiss and stare at nothing then run suddenly away.<p>
<p>Sit and stare destroy couch scratch the box or sleep yet sit on human so burrow under covers, cereal boxes make for five star accommodation.<p>
</div>
```

So it doesn't apply here. You can do it with `display: flex`;.

```css
.fake-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.fake-cell {
  flex: 45%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="fake-table">
  <div class="fake-row">
    <div class="fake-cell first">
      <strong>Word</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="fake-cell last">
      Example text.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fake-row">
    <div class="fake-cell first">
      <strong>Word 2</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="fake-cell last">
      Example text 2.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`flex-shrink: 0;` blocks shrinking of columns, so fake table's columns have the same width.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CSS-Grid` solution for this. A more generic one. You will need less HTML code as well. (*Please note: This is a more generic solution, you will need to come up with some changes as per your requirement*)

**CODEPEN LINK:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/dypQjrv

**FULL CODE:**

```css
.container{
  display:grid;
  width:960px;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  gap:1rem;
}

.container div{
  background:#ccc;
  padding:1rem;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="td english">where?</div>
        <div class="ex">Curi?</div>
        <div class="td english"><span class="u">Where</span> is Antonio's house?</div>
        <div class="ex"><span class="u">xx</span> xxx?</div>
  
          <div class="td english">where?</div>
        <div class="ex">Curi?</div>
        <div class="td english"><span class="u">Where</span> is Antonio's house?</div>
        <div class="ex"><span class="u">xx</span> xxx?</div>
        
</div>
```